# Calculating the pressure in a rotating bucket

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, pressure, fluid-statics, centrifugal-force

[image]

By the way, I am not quite convinced that the solution should be $\frac{1}{2}\rho\omega^2r^2$. I think it should be $\rho\omega^2r^2$. Appreciate any help.

Comment: Please use MathJax to write equations and avoid difficult to read photos. Link- https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can get that by solving this equation:

$$\vec \nabla P = - \rho \cdot \vec a$$

substitue $a = \omega^2\cdot r \cdot \hat r$

and solve the equation.

(Full answer cannot be provided because of homework-exercises tag)

How is the above equation derived? 
$\mathbf{\vec \nabla P = - \rho \cdot \vec a}$

Take a small volume of liquid in the container $dV = dx \cdot dy \cdot dz$

Assume the **liquid is incompressible**, therefore the **small volumetric section can be assumed as solid rigid block.**

Writing newton laws for the small block:

$$d\vec F = \delta m\cdot \vec a$$

$$\because m = \rho \cdot \delta V$$
$$d\vec F = \rho \cdot \delta V\cdot \vec a$$

$when \ \delta \rightarrow 0 ; \ \delta V = dV$

$$\mathbf{d\vec F = \rho \cdot dx \cdot dy \cdot dz \cdot \vec a}$$

$$d\vec F_x = P_x \cdot dz \cdot dy$$
$$d\vec F_y = P_y \cdot dz \cdot dx$$
$$d\vec F_z = P_z \cdot dx \cdot dy$$

$$dF_x \hat i + dF_y \hat j + dF_z \hat k = \rho \cdot dx \cdot dy \cdot dz \cdot \vec a$$

$$\mathbf{P_x \cdot dz \cdot dy \hat i + P_y \cdot dz \cdot dx \hat j + P_z \cdot dx \cdot dy \hat k = \rho \cdot dx \cdot dy \cdot dz \cdot \vec a}$$

**dividing both sides by $dx \cdot dy \cdot dz$**

$$\cfrac{P_x}{dx} \hat i + \cfrac{P_y}{dy} \hat j + \cfrac{P_z}{dz} \hat k = \rho \cdot \vec a$$

**since pressure at bottom is more than above net force is in above direction**, therefore

$$\mathbf{\cfrac{P_x}{dx} \hat i + \cfrac{P_y}{dy} \hat j + \cfrac{P_z}{dz} \hat k = -\rho \cdot \vec a}$$

Above can be written as: (in shorthand)

$$\mathbf{\vec \nabla P = - \rho \cdot \vec a}$$

---

[image: look for better understanding]

Comment: If any confusion please comment

Comment: Can you please explain how you got this equation? Thank you, Dr-Paradox.

Comment: Thank you is much. Got it now.